# How to split text horizontally equal on left and right side of element on overflow?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to achieve the following effect for div content while user type text inside div (`contentEditable="true"`).
[image]

```css
.editor {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="editor" contentEditable="true">
  <p>type here ...
    <p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

```css
.editor {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    outline: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left:25%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
.editor p {
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="editor" contentEditable="true"><p>type here ...<p></div>
```

Comment: Only one issue with this is while on ENTER next line is overlapping with first one. @fpintodacosta

Comment: You are definitely right, @Sagar Kharche, thanks. I'd say this would only work as a solution for a single line input requirement. Some JS would be required in order to space/position a new `<p>` tag accordingly on newline.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like the following:

```js
var contents = document.getElementsByClassName('content');

for(let i = 0; i < contents.length; i++)
{
  var content = contents[i];
  var editor = content.parentElement;
  var width = content.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  content.style.setProperty('--content-width', width+'px');
  
  
  editor.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var width = content.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  content.style.setProperty('--content-width', width+'px');
  });
}
```

```css
.editor {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: 0;
  position: relative;
  left:25%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.editor p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: auto;
  min-width: var(--content-width);
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(-1 * (var(--content-width) / 4));
}
```

```html
<div class="editor" contentEditable="true"><p class="content">type here ...<p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p {
  position: relative;
  right: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Add this to your code.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```css
.input-outline {
      width: 100px;
      margin: 25px auto;
      border: 1px solid green;
      position: relative;
      height: 500px;
    }
    
    input {
      width: 300px;
      border: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: -100%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      background: transparent;
    }
```

```html
<div class="input-outline">
      <input type="text" value="this a long text blablabla heheheheeheheheheh">
    </div>
```